# Cycle between modes in fzf.vim

Tags: plugin-ctrlp, plugin-fzf

I'm using fzf.vim instead of ctrlp.vim for quite some time now but there is one functionality that a miss quite a lot. In ctrlp.vim once you have the extension opened you can cycle between modes using the `<c-f>` and `<c-b>`. This for me was very useful when switching from buffers to files search of vice versa while keeping everything that I have typed into the search by that point. Is there any way to do that in fzf.vim for `:Files`, `:Buffers` commands respectively?

Comment: I would think about defining a mapping for the right type of buffer for FZF so that it would close the current buffer of FZF(IIRC it is terminal), and open `:Files` or `:Buffers`